# How to set zh-CN as the default label for Gradio Component

Tags: python, gradio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIVb6.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfFGt.png)

How to set Chinese as the default label for Gradio Component，I found the translation in simplified Chinese has been implemented，but still confused about how to configure it in the code
https://github.com/gradio-app/gradio/blob/main/js/app/src/lang/zh-CN.json

```
import gradio as gr

def test(text):
    return text

iface = gr.Interface(
    fn=test,
    title="Test Gradio",
    inputs=[
        gr.Textbox(label="input")
    ],
    outputs=gr.Textbox(label="output")
)

iface.launch(auth=[("admin","password")])
```